# Why does my mock object not recognize any calls to it?

Tags: python, unit-testing, patch, python-decorators, assertion

Here's some unit test that I have reduced to a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

```
import unittest
import zipfile
from unittest.mock import patch

"""My 'production' function"""
def list_txt_in_zipfile(zip_file_path):
    with open(zip_file_path, "rb") as file:
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
        print("zipfile.ZipFile is", zipfile.ZipFile)
    return [f_name for f_name in zf.namelist() if f_name.endswith(".txt")]


class UnzipperTest(unittest.TestCase):

    """My test method"""
    @patch("__main__.zipfile.ZipFile")
    def test_list_txt_in_zipfile(self, mock_ZipFile):
        txt_list = list_txt_in_zipfile("my.txt.zip")
        mock_ZipFile.assert_any_call() # AssertionError
        print("mock_ZipFile is", mock_ZipFile)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The AssertionError:

```
AssertionError: ZipFile() call not found
```

When my test method calls the `list_txt_in_zipfile` it logs a mock object, not the real `zipfile.Zipfile` (from Python's `zipfile.py`).

If I print those "two" objects `zipfile.ZipFile` in my production function and `mock_ZipFile` in my test method, they are the very same object:

```
zipfile.ZipFile is <MagicMock name='ZipFile' id='3069297420'>
mock_ZipFile is <MagicMock name='ZipFile' id='3069297420'>
```

Why does `mock_ZipFile` fail to assert any calls to it?

I've actually succeeded testing the `list_txt_in_zipfile` function by splitting it into two functions (the `open()` part and the rest from `zipfile.ZipFile()`, but as it stands now this isn't a huge function, so I would like to keep this piece of logic in one place.

UPDATE: The `my.txt.zip` in the test method actually exists, I haven't managed to bring in `unittest.mock.mock_open` to mock out `open()` because I got stuck with mocking out `zipfile.ZipFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert_any_call` asserts that the mock object has been called *with the specified arguments*. You're not passing any arguments in your assertion, but in the function itself `zipfile.Zipfile()` is called with one argument, a file object.

Comment: Valid point. I actually had trouble finding out what to put into the orignal assert_called_once_with, so I've mistaken assert_any_call to be a method that passes given no specific list of arguments.

Comment: The help() also says _"The assert passes if the mock has *ever* been called, unlike
    `assert_called_with` and `assert_called_once_with` that only pass if
    the call is the most recent one."_

Comment: Again, in conjunction with the first sentence, that implies "ever (with the specified arguments)". If you just want to assert it has been called, use `assert_called()`

Comment: Thank you again. I've stuffed in `unittest.mock.ANY` into `assert_any_call` and it passes now.